# CreateFile function fail reading a file even if it exists, error code -1

Tags: shell, assembly, reverse-engineering, createfile, ollydbg

Trying to reverse a windows executable, I found the function `creatfile` that tries to open a file in read only mode,

[image]

I create the file in the very same directory with the same name given to the function, but it always fail with a error code -1, and I'd like to figure out why.

[image]

The value of the `eax` register after the function call is -1, here is the output of `dir` command from the very same directory

[image]

Any idea why it fails?

Comment: You need to use GetLastError() to get the actual cause of the problem.  Note that this value is stored in the TIB if you need to do this entirely within the debugger.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - You know, I wondered about that.  Is ollydbg showing the "escaped c" syntax for "\"?  If so, then `\BabyDriver` is going to be a problem.  If not, then what does `\\.` mean?  Under Windows, "\\" normally indicates a network path?

Comment: maybe this will help: https://superuser.com/questions/64471/create-rename-a-file-folder-that-begins-with-a-dot-in-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\\.\` notation is not used for ordinary files. It is used for devices. So creating a regular file will not work here. Instead you need to create a device with that name. Those names are also common in device drivers - hence probably the naming of this task.

Refer to section "Win32 Device Namespaces" in [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#win32_device_namespaces) for more info.